# How to connect carousel with navigation bar in kivymd?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I am making an app in kivymd where there is a bottom navigation bar with three bottom nav elements(home, plus, profile). I want That on pressing home a carousel with a three line avatar list get's shown. But if a write my code under navigation element (home) it sort of comes in middle. And if I write the code inside main boxlayout the content of other buttons comes underneath.
following is my code with code under nav element being commented:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

Window.size = (375, 667)
kv = """
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    padding: 0
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Ad 'O Square"
        md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        specific_text_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        elevation: 10
    Carousel:
        direction: "right" 
        Image:
            source: "Colors/red.jpg"
        Image:
            source: "Colors/green.png"
        Image:
            source: "Colors/blue.png"
    ThreeLineAvatarListItem:
        text: "Product 1"
        secondary_text: "Short Text"
        tertiary_text: "Rating"

        ImageLeftWidget:
            source: "Colors/red.jpg"



    ThreeLineAvatarListItem:
        text: "Product 2"
        secondary_text: "Short Text"
        tertiary_text: "Rating"

        ImageLeftWidget:
            source: "Colors/blue.png"


    ThreeLineAvatarListItem:
        text: "Product 3"
        secondary_text: "Short Text"
        tertiary_text: "Rating"

        ImageLeftWidget:
            source: "Colors/green.png"
    

    MDBottomNavigation:
        panel_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 1'
            text: 'home'
            icon: 'home'
            # Carousel:
            #     direction: "right" 
            #     Image:
            #         source: "Colors/red.jpg"
            #     Image:
            #         source: "Colors/green.png"
            #     Image:
            #         source: "Colors/blue.png"
            # ThreeLineAvatarListItem:
            #     text: "Product 1"
            #     secondary_text: "Short Text"
            #     tertiary_text: "Rating"
            # 
            #     ImageLeftWidget:
            #         source: "Colors/red.jpg"
            # 
            # 
            # ThreeLineAvatarListItem:
            #     text: "Product 2"
            #     secondary_text: "Short Text"
            #     tertiary_text: "Rating"
            # 
            #     ImageLeftWidget:
            #         source: "Colors/blue.png"
            # 
            # 
            # ThreeLineAvatarListItem:
            #     text: "Product 3"
            #     secondary_text: "Short Text"
            #     tertiary_text: "Rating"
            # 
            #     ImageLeftWidget:
            #         source: "Colors/green.png"        



        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 2'
            icon: 'plus-circle-outline'
            
            MDLabel:
                text: "Screen 2"
                halign: "center"
                
                
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 3'
            text: 'profile'
            icon: 'account'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Profile'
                halign: 'center'
"""


class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Red"
        screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7VCj.jpg)

[and this is the output when I write the code inside bottom navigation element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKYcQ.png)